# Background-size: cover not working in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I'm currently using Carousel property for my website and I'm not able to use background-size: cover, in order for the pictures in my carousel to "stretch" to the full size of the browser. How do I go around that?

Note: The reason why I did what I did below in my code block is because, the images are too big so I did "w-auto", to resize the image to how it looks now.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <div class="cover">
      <img class="d-block w-auto" src="./assets/img/mcdonalds/2.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="cover">
      <img class="d-block w-auto" src="./assets/img/mcdonalds/3.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="cover">
      <img class="d-block w-auto" src="./assets/img/mcdonalds/4.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
.cover {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, `background-size: cover;` is applied to the image set to background using css. And here you have `img` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give `background-size` property if there is a `background-image`. In your case you have used an `img` tag so instead for the `img` tag use this properties:

`width: 100%;
height: 250px;
object-fit: cover;`

where you can give height as the height you desire to have.

Comment: This works, but it cuts off a part of my image, how do I make it responsive?

Comment: in that case keep only `width: 100%` and remove the other properties.

Comment: That would make my image way too big, how do I adjust the height so it doesn't cut off a part of my image? I have trouble doing that and that only, sadly.

Comment: in the above answer you can use `object-fit: contain` instead to get the full image displayed, but it will try to maintain the images aspect ratio so you will be left with a blank space on the left and right of your image. Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/603prvxg/